# excel define more than one variable

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I am working to write an excel macro. I want my macro loop exactly 100 times. In first iteration it reads one file called file1.txt. Copies data from it and pastes data into one main excel file cell "E4". After that it reads second file called file2.txt and copies data from it then pastes data into the main excel file cell "H4". 100 iterations must be done like that.

But currently it copies data from file1.txt and pastes data into "E4", "H4", "K4", "N4" ..etc (100 times) respectively. After 100 iteerations it starts copying data from file2.txt and pastes over "E4" again and, "H4", "K4", "N4"...    After 100 loops file3.txt.

So it makes a total 100x100 loops, and overwrites all results with the last files'. I want only 100 loops, and result of each file in a different column. How can I do that?
Sorry for my poor English.

```
 Sub copy_files_macro()

 Dim y As Integer
 Dim fname As String
 Dim dirctry As String
 Dim profnum As Integer

Sheets("Start_Page").Select
dirctry = Range("A1").Value
fname = Range("A2").Value

ChDir (dirctry)
  For profnum = 1 To 100
  For y = 1 To 300 Step 3

    Workbooks.OpenText filename:= _
    fname & "file" & profnum & ".txt", Origin:=857, _
    StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(9, _
    1), Array(29, 1), Array(49, 1), Array(69, 1), Array(89, 1), Array(109, 1), Array(129, 1), _
    Array(149, 1), Array(168, 1), Array(188, 1), Array(209, 1), Array(229, 1), Array(249, 1), _
    Array(269, 1), Array(288, 1))
    TrailingMinusNumbers = True
Range("B3:C123").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("main_excel_file.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("file_data").Select
Range("D4").Offset(0, y).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows(fname & "file" & profnum & ".txt").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.Close

Next y
Next profnum
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the extra loop over `y` and replace `Offset(0,y)` with `Offset(0,1+(profnum-1)*3)`

That would give the following:

```
Sub copy_files_macro()

 Dim fname As String
 Dim dirctry As String
 Dim profnum As Integer

  Sheets("Start_Page").Select
  dirctry = Range("A1").Value
  fname = Range("A2").Value

  ChDir (dirctry)
  For profnum = 1 To 100

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
    fname & "file" & profnum & ".txt", Origin:=857, _
    StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(9, _
    1), Array(29, 1), Array(49, 1), Array(69, 1), Array(89, 1), Array(109, 1), Array(129, 1), _
    Array(149, 1), Array(168, 1), Array(188, 1), Array(209, 1), Array(229, 1), Array(249, 1), _
    Array(269, 1), Array(288, 1))

    TrailingMinusNumbers = True
    Range("B3:C123").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("main_excel_file.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("file_data").Select
    Range("D4").Offset(0, 1 + (profnum - 1) * 3).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows(fname & "file" & profnum & ".txt").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWindow.Close

  Next profnum
  ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```